how to print editortype in bibliography using jurabib
I am using the jurabib package for my legal dissertation. I have encountered a problem I don't know how to solve. In @commented theres an entry field called "editortype". It should be printed in the bibliography, but it doesn't. You can find this entry field in the package documentation and it seems like the entry is also printed, but in my document it doesn't. I am using the jurabook class (i know that it's old, but the editortype field is the only thing not working). I hope you guys can help me, because I didn't manage to get biblatex working on my Mac. That's the minimal working example:
\documentclass[%
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  german,
  ]{jurabook}
  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{jurabib}

%% jurabib
\jurabibsetup{
authorformat=dynamic,
commabeforerest,
titleformat={commasep,all,noreplace},
annotatorformat=italic,
commabeforerest,
bibformat={ibidem,compress},
dotafter=bibentry,
howcited=normal
}

\bibliographystyle{jurabib}


\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@commented{GrigoleitAktG,
 author = {Grigoleit, Hans},
 editortype = {(Hrsg.)},
 year = {2020},
 title = {Aktiengesetz},
 titleaddon = {Kommentar},
 volume = {},
 volumetitle = {},
 shortauthor = {Grigoleit},
 shorttitle  = {AktG},
 howcited = {1},
 address = {M{\"u}nchen},
edition = {2},
gender = {Sm}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite[Grigoleit][§ 1 Rn. 1]{GrigoleitAktG}

\bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}


The omission of proper capitalisation and contractions make your text rather unpleasant to read.

Is it better now?

A bit better now, but the i could still be improved.

Now I see. English is not my maternal language.

Most people here aren't native speakers - which makes it even more important to stick to common usage of the English language.

I just had to change "author" to "editor", now everything works fine.
